# Summing large primes takes time! How do I make it more efficient?

Tags: python, primes

I'm trying to complete [Project Euler's 10th problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=10), but the code I currently have takes so much time it hasn't been able to complete.

I've looked around but I haven't been able to find out how to make the code take a shorter time.

This is the code I have:

```
def IsPrime(num):
    for i in range(2, num/2):
        if num % i == 0:
            prime = False
            return prime
    prime = True
    return prime

def SumOfPrime(limit):
    primesum=2+3    #For some reason my prime finder doesn't allow numbers below 5
    for check in range(5,limit):
        prime=IsPrime(check)
        if prime == True:
            primesum += check
    return primesum^2

print(SumOfPrime(2000000))
```

The correct answer should be `142913828922`, however, as previously mentioned I don't get an output entirely. Is there any way to make this code faster?

Comment: `for i in range(2, num/2):` I would set the upper limit to `int(sqrt(num))+1`, I could also give a more efficient algorithm but you want to speed up this one right?

Comment: That helped a lot! I get the correct result and now it takes ```32.98 sec``` for it to finish. I'd love to see a faster algorithm as it, of course, isn't perfect.

Comment: Hmm you could also save the found primes in a list and check if a number is a prime dividing by only the primes that you found earlier, if you want a better way to find primes checkout https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: Looks interesting, thanks a lot! Maybe post those two things as an answer so I can mark the question as solved? =)

Comment: Since 2 is the only even prime, in your `IsPrime` method, you could check 2 as a divisor and then only check odd divisors: 3, 5, 7, 9,11, ... up to the square root.  Not as efficient as a sieve but should halve the time spent checking a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some tips to speed up your implementation:

- You only have to check for a divisor until the square root of a number, the product of two numbers bigger that it will give a bigger result.
- You could also only search for prime divisors, maybe adding the found primes in a list or something like that.

It you want a more efficient algorithm, please checkout https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Answer (score 0):

> now it takes 32.98 sec for it to finish. I'd love to see a faster
>   algorithm

You should use a *Sieve of Eratosthenes*.  Ignoring that, this rework should get your time under 10 seconds:

```
def isPrime(number):
    if number <= 2:
        return number == 2

    if number % 2 == 0:
        return False

    for divisor in range(3, int(number ** 0.5) + 1, 2):
        if number % divisor == 0:
            return False

    return True

def sumOfPrimes(limit):
    return sum(number for number in range(limit) if isPrime(number))

print(sumOfPrimes(2000000))
```

Handle *even* numbers as a special case in `isPrime()` and then just deal with *odd* divisors.  Using a *comprehension* or *generator expression* pushes more of your looping code down to **C** level and usually gets you a little more speed.

Comment: After some testing I used the same code with the only difference 
```if number == 2: return True```
just testing numbers from 1-10000, the code finished in 13.549189329147339 sec

When testing with the following code:
```def IsPrime(num):
    for i in range(2,int((num**0.5)+1)):
        if num % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```
It takes ```13.15842890739441``` secs
I wonder why the first one's pretty much the same as the second, even though it only analyzes half the numbers ... Anyone got a reason for that?

Comment: @Thomas.B, testing numbers up to 10,000 should only take a fraction of a second, not 13 seconds.  The change you made shows no timing difference on my system as the range of numbers is too small.  At around 100,000 the difference surfaces.

Comment: I just noticed the error. I meant to write 1,000,000. I don't know how I changed the amount of zeros that much.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Sieve of Eratosthenes:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Mar 13 2017, 20:56:15)
[GCC 5.4.0] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def sumPrimes(n):
...     i, p, ps, m, sum = 0, 3, [2], n // 2, 2
...     sieve = [True] * m
...     while p <= n:
...         if sieve[i]:
...             sum += p
...             for j in range((p*p-3)/2, m, p):
...                 sieve[j] = False
...         i, p = i+1, p+2
...     return sum
...
>>> from time import time
>>> start = time(); print sumPrimes(2000000); print time() - start
142913828922
0.262000083923
```

About a quarter of a second on my machine.

Comment: On my machine, in Python 3, this blows up with, "TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer".  In Python 2, it returns the wrong result for `n == 2` or less.

Comment: There are no floats anywhere in the algorithm, unless you pass a float as the argument `n`. I have Python 2.7.13 installed. It works fine. `sumPrimes(2)` properly returns 2. I did not bother with error-checking the cases for `n` less than 2 or for `n` a float. I modified my answer to show headers and timing information.

Comment: In Python 3, `(p*p-3)/2` is a floating point value and passing it to `range()` generates the error I quoted above.  (Not due to `n` being a float.)  Consider `//` (integer division) instead.  If you follow the OP's link to the Euler problem, the function sums the primes *less than* `n`.  So the result for `n == 2` is `0`, your `2` result is incorrect.

Comment: @cdlane the answer clearly states it's a Python 2.7.13 code, so why should we concern ourselves with Python 3? As for the 2, it can be easily special cased, so it's not a problem either, yes? I followed the link, and what is asked for there is a solution for 2,000,000, not for 2.

Comment: @WillNess, the answer didn't clearly state it's Python 2.7.3 code until *after* I wrote my comment.  And both issues are easily fixable under Python 2.

Comment: @cdlane they need no fixing under Python 2 though.